# Make attribute readable/writable but not overridable/redeclarable?

Tags: java

Is it possible to prevent subclasses from overriding/redeclaring a class attribute but still let them read it & write it?

```
class Human
{
    public boolean isMale;
    ...
}

class Asian extends Human
{
    public void livingLife()
    {
         // this is OK
         (isMale) ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();

         // this is OK
         isMale = false;
    }

    // redeclaration is not OK
    public boolean isMale;
}
```

Comment: Why isn't redeclaration okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it private and provide accessors.

```
class Human
{
    private boolean isMale;

    public boolean isMale() {
        return isMale;
    }

    public void setIsMale(boolean isMale) {
        this.isMale = isMale;
    }
}
```

Note that you cannot avoid redeclaration.

Comment: Not even with some kind of annotation? note that i need to prevent variable name redeclaration. private doesnt do this (Maybe like @DoesNotOverride?)

Comment: @Alan Fields can't be overridden by subclasses. The worst a subclass can do is declare a new field with the same name, but it will have a separate scope.

Comment: @4castle Hey 4castle, I'm not trying to break the rules or anything. I know of best practices and OOP programming. Im just asking if it is possible to do this and if not (make a @DoesNotOverride) decorator to achieve the same results

Comment: Reclaring is not overriding.